# Do (equal) increases in performance provide advantages to any party?

Tags: encryption, performance

Assume a cryptographic algorithm in which the performance for the good guys (the ones that know the key) grows linearly with the length of the key, and for which the only way to break it is a brute-force attack of trying all possible keys. Suppose the performance for the good guys is adequate (e.g., it can encrypt and decrypt as fast as the bits can be transmitted over the wire) at a give key size. Then suppose advances in computer technology make computers twice as fast. Given that both the good guys and the bad guys get faster computers, does this advance in computer speed work to the advantage of the good guys, the bad guys, or does it not make any difference?

Comment: that almost literally describes the current state of symmetric cryptography, the solution is to make the key long enough that the bad guys can never win

Comment: _"the performance for the good guys (the ones that know the key) grows linearly with the length of the key"_ has a direction issue: the performance _decrease_ with the size of the key (or that to a small power, much less than 2). But the conclusion in the [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/59302/555) remains correct.

Answer (score 2):

Since searching by brute force an $n$ bit long key takes an exponential time ($2^n$ possible keys), the advances in technology benefits the good guy. For example, adding 1 bit to the key doubles the search time for the bad guy, but requires only 1 more step for the good guy.